# Force synchronous looping of http requests

Tags: asynchronous, request

I've been struggling with this piece of code for a while and I'm reaching out for help. I have a array of dates and I"m trying to make http requests in order of the array and to write the return information, also in order.

Here is my code:

```
const dateArray = ['november-22-2019', 'november-25-2019', 'november-26-2019', 'november-27-2019', 'november-29-2019'];

async function loppThroughArray() {
    for (const date of dateArray) {
        const options = {
            url: process.env.URL + date
        };
        await asyncRequest(options, date);
    }
}

async function asyncRequest(options, date) {
    request(options, function(error, response, html) {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return;
        }
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const content = $('.entry-content');
        const formattedContent = content.text()
            .split('\t').join('')
            .split('\n\n\n').join('')
            .split('\n\n').join('');
        const dataToBeWritten = '### ' + date + '\n' + formattedContent + '\n\n';
        fs.appendFileSync(`./WODs/${currentDate}.md`, dataToBeWritten, 'utf-8', {'flags':'a+'});
        fs.appendFileSync(`./WODs/${currentDate}.txt`, dataToBeWritten, 'utf-8', {'flags':'a+'});
    });
}

loppThroughArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using a version of 'request' that uses promises instead of callbacks. See code:

```
async function loppThroughArray() {
    for (const date of dateArray) {
        const options = {
            url: process.env.URL + date
        };
        await asyncRequest(options, date);
        console.log('fetching: ', date);
    }
}

async function asyncRequest(options, date) {
    await rp(options)
        .then(function(html){
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const content = $('.entry-content');
            const formattedContent = content.text()
            .split('\t').join('')
            .split('\n\n\n').join('')
            .split('\n\n').join('');
            const dataToBeWritten = '### ' + date + '\n' + formattedContent + '\n\n';
            fs.appendFileSync(`./WODs/${currentDate}.md`, dataToBeWritten, 'utf-8', {'flags':'a+'});
            fs.appendFileSync(`./WODs/${currentDate}.txt`, dataToBeWritten, 'utf-8', {'flags':'a+'});
        });
}

loppThroughArray();
```